# Why is the `cp` command giving me "will not create hard link" messages when I never asked it to create links?

Tags: command-line, cp

I recently ran the command `cp --update --verbose -r ./* "E:\Backup m.d.y"` and now I am seeing messages like this appear:

> cp: will not create hard link `E:\Backup m.d.y/Python
>   Programs/PracticalTheoremProverSite/ptp-site/node_modules/memory-fs/node_modules/readable-stream/doc/wg-meetings'
>   to directory `E:\Backup
>   m.d.y/CS189/Code/final-project/.git/objects/89'

Why is the copy command printing messages like this? What do these two locations even have to do with one another?

Comment: Which shell are you using? Bash doesn't use E:\Backup and PowerShell doesn't have things like `verbose`

Comment: Command Prompt is what I'm using

Comment: no, there's no `cp` in cmd, unless you put cygwin's path into your path. But even in that case `cp` is a Unix tool and it won't accept a Windows path like `E:\Backup`

Comment: Oh, so this is some weird thing that only magically happens to work probably because I have the Windows Subsystem for Linux installed on my machine, and somehow that allows me to use the command in Command Prompt? Weird...

Comment: Note that it did actually run though, so I'm not sure how it didn't accept the Windows path.

Comment: of course it'll work but not as you expected. `E:\Backup m.d.y` is a file named exactly like that in the current directory, because `:` is a valid character in Unix file names, and `\B` is some invalid escape which will be treated as literal `\B`, and `\ ` is also valid in file names in Unix